# disallow access of internal files in liferay

Tags: .htaccess, liferay, file-access

In liferay I have 
 --tomcat
      --webapps 
       --**myimages** 
    --**my-portlet** 
So using code in **my-portlet** I have given links to given file in **myimages** folder for a specific user.
 Link would be 
http://localhost:8080/myimages/User1.jpg

**Problem Statement:** I have to restrict a user (rather than defined role in liferay) so that s/he should not be able to access any of the files in **myimages** folder as s/he user hits on direct above link. 
**What I have tested:**

1. I have checked **.htaccess** file will **NOT** be useful since liferay has
   tomcat rather than apache server.
2. Created a **filter class** by which I can intercept any request made
   should process through.
3. [openLDAP](http://liferay-alfresco.blogspot.in/2013/08/ldap-authentication-with-apache2.html) can not use since we are having separate authentication
   mechanism. 
   So if anyone has idea how to deal with this security issue, please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

URLs that are resolved through individual webapps (like `myimages`), thus not through Liferay, will not have any idea of the user that accesses Liferay: They'll be well shielded from the other (and in this case totally unrelated) webapplication Liferay.

What you can do is to provide these files through portlet plugins and serve the images through resource-URLs in the portlet. This properly goes through the portal context (in fact, the URLs will point to Liferay, despite the implementation in a different webapplication) and you'll be able to check the permissions of the current user. Then just read the file and pipe it into the `ResourceResponse`'s output stream.

If the files indeed are static web resources, you might want to put them in myimages/WEB-INF/images - as tomcat will refuse to directly serve everything under WEB-INF, but your portlet will be able to access these files.